# Question on compactly supported cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

As Harder wrote in his "Lectures on algebraic geometry I", page 120 : Let $X$ be a locally compact space and $\mathcal{F}$ a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$. If we have a section $s \in H^0(X, \mathcal{F})$ then its support $\operatorname{Supp}(s)=|s|$ is the set of $x \in X$ with $s_x \neq 0$. It is always closed. If we have an open subset $U \subset X$ and a section $s \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ then its support $|s|$ is closed in $U$ but not necessarily in $X$.
We can define the submodule $H_c^0(X, \mathcal{F})$ of sections with compact support. This yields a left exact functor and we define the cohomology with compact supports as the right derived functor of $H_c^0(X, \mathcal{F})$. In accordance with our general principles we choose an injective resolution
$$
0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{F} \longrightarrow I^0 \longrightarrow I^1 \longrightarrow \ldots
$$
of $\mathcal{F}$ and define
$$
H_c^i(X, \mathcal{F})=H^i\left(H_c^0\left(X, I^{\bullet}\right)\right)
$$

Let us assume that $U \stackrel{i}{\hookrightarrow} X$ is an open subset of our space, and let us assume that its closure is compact, then its boundary $\partial \bar{U}=\bar{U} \backslash U$ is also compact. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on $U$. We define two new sheaves on $X$ : The direct image $i_*(\mathcal{F})$ where
$$
i_*(\mathcal{F})(V)=\mathcal{F}(U \cap V)
$$
and the extension by zero
$$
i_{!}(\mathcal{F})(V)=\{s \in \mathcal{F}(V \cap U)|| s \mid \text { does not meet } V \cap \partial \bar{U}\}
$$
One checks easily that $i_{!}(\mathcal{F})$ has the stalks
$$
\begin{aligned}
& i_{!}(\mathcal{F})_x=\mathcal{F}_x \quad \text { if } \quad x \in U \\
& i_{!}(\mathcal{F})_y=0 \quad \text { if } \quad y \notin U .
\end{aligned}
$$
We have a morphism of sheaves $i_{!}(\mathcal{F}) \longrightarrow i_*(\mathcal{F})$ which is an isomorphism in all stalks except the ones on the boundary $\partial \bar{U}$.

Proposition 4.7.1. If $X$ is a locally compact space and $i: U \hookrightarrow X$ an open subset with compact closure and if $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf of abelian groups on $U$ then
$$
H_c^{\bullet}(U, \mathcal{F})=H^{\bullet}\left(X, i_{!}(\mathcal{F})\right)
$$
Proof: This is almost clear from the definition. We choose an injective resolution of the sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $U$
$$
0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{F} \longrightarrow I^0 \longrightarrow I^1 \longrightarrow I^2 \longrightarrow \ldots
$$
and we notice that
$$
i_{!}\left(I^{\bullet}\right)(X)=H_c^0\left(U, I^{\bullet}\right) .
$$

I don't see why we can compute
$$
H^{\bullet}\left(X, i_{!}(\mathcal{F})\right)
$$
using $i_{!}$ , it's exact but it doesn't map injectives to injectives. Does it map flabby sheaves to flabby sheaves?

Comment: As Harder writes *where* exactly?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Lectures on algebraic geometry I

Comment: Add that to the actual text of the question. It is really very bad scholarship to attribute things to people and not provide minimal details on where one can actually find the thing.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks. I've realized it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there is the notion of a c-soft sheaf which behaves nicely with respect to $f_{!}$ for any continuous function $f$ between locally compact Hausdorff spaces.

Flabby (hence injective) sheaves are always c-soft, and $f_{!}(F)$ is c-soft if $F$ is c-soft. c-soft sheaves do form an adopted class for $f_{!}$ meaning you can compute the derived functors by taking a resolution by c-soft sheaves instead of injective sheaves. Moreover, if the space is countable at infinity (a union of countably many compact subspaces), then c-soft sheaves also form an adopted class for the global sections functor.

For more details (and proofs of the above statements), take a look at Definition 2.5.5, Proposition 2.5.7, 2.5.8 and 2.5.10 (pages 104-106) from "Sheaves on Manifolds" by Kashiwara and  Schapira.